# Is there a better way to listen for changes than polling?

Tags: esp32, polling, micropython

I’m writing some micropython code to run on an esp32 microcontroller and I’m not certain I’m doing this the best way. Basically, I am polling a robovac to find out if it is charging or cleaning so my code can respond accordingly. I feel this may have some negative long-term impact on the vacuum as it’s probably not designed for constant polling, but I have no factual basis for this opinion! Is there a better way?

I’m doing something like this:

```
#vac object created

while True:
  currentStatus = vac.Status()
  if currentStatus == ‘cleaning’:
    #do this stuff
  else:
    #do this stuff 
  time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the device. If it offers an interrupt line, you could use that, but it likely doesn't. In the microcontroller world, polling is very normal. And polling on the order of 0.5Hz is not fast.

If you're more used to working at higher levels of abstraction, keep in mind that many things that look like "block until event" are implemented by polling at a lower level.